# How do I get react-native-inappbrowser-reborn to trigger success upon successful Facebook login

Tags: react-native, facebook-apps

I'm trying to setup a manual flow for Facebook login, as per the docs at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

I've got my test Facebook app working as expected, i.e., I can login using a private web browser window fine. The URL I'm using is:

```
https://facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=<app_id>&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

Now within my React-Native app, I'm using `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` to present a `SFAuthenticationSession` on iOS. As per their docs (at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn), I'm doing the following:

```
const redirectUri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
const url = "https://facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id="+appId+"&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"

InAppBrowser.isAvailable()
.then(() => {
InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectUri, {
    // iOS Properties
    dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
    // Android Properties
    showTitle: false,
    enableUrlBarHiding: true,
    enableDefaultShare: true,
})
.then((response) => {
    // Only gets to this point if user explicitly cancels.
    // So this does not trigger upon successful login.
})
// catch handlers follow
```

Using the above, my app correctly open up an in-app browser and I can login fine using a test user for my test app. Upon successful login though, I don't get redirected back to the `.then` completion handler. It just stays in the in-app browser view and I see the same message from Facebook that I see when logging in using a web browser. It says something like "Success. Please treat the url the same as you would a password", or something like that.

I may be missing something here, but I thought the purpose of passing `redirectUri` as an argument to `openAuth` was so that upon redirection to that URI, the completion handler would be triggered.

**Question:** How do I redirect back to the completion handler upon login success?

Comment: Ohh but redirectUri only works with deep linking, can you try adding that redirection from Facebook?

Comment: Hey, I put a step for step instruction, how you can do the redirection. Unfortunately facebook's api will not call your app directly via deeplink. You have to do it by your self using your own api.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you already have a solution but thought it might be useful for someone else facing this issue. If you don't have a solution so far follow my instructions:

You can't directly redirect back to your application using deep link, since Facebook will not call a link `like myapplicationname://mycustompath´. It's only possible to call links using the https-protocol (https://...).

The solution I'd suggest you to use is to redirect using your own API (Facebook -> Your API -> Deep Link Redirection). You will understand why this is required in the most of the real world applications at the end of the instructions.

Starting from your react-native app call the authorize endpoint of Facebook with a redirection to your application and set the global deeplink of your app as redirect uri.

```js
    InAppBrowser.close();
    InAppBrowser.openAuth("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOURCLIENTID&redirect_uri=https://YOURDOMAIN:PORT/auth/facebook", "{YOURAPPSDEEPLINKNAME}://{SOMEPATHYOUWANTTOEND}")
    .then((response) => { 
         handleAuthorized(response, LOGINTYPE.FACEBOOK);
    });
```

Now after login you'll be redirected to your API with the authorization code token as query parameter (e.g. `https://YOURDOMAIN:PORT/auth/facebook?code=AVERYLONGCODESENTBYFACEBOOK`)

Using this code token from the query parameter, you make another API Call to get the access_token for the user

{GET}:  `https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://YOURDOMAIN:PORT/auth/facebook&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&code=AVERYLONGCODESENTBYFACEBOOK`

Facebook's API will send you an answer as JSON with the access_token inside.
You can make another call using the access token of the user, to get the userId and the username

{GET}: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_SENT_BY_FACEBOOK_IN_PREVIOUS_GET_REQUEST`.

If you need the e-mail address for the user you have to make another call. Make sure you'd set the permission to read the e-mail address for your app on the developer portal of facebook.
The following request will return you the id, name and the email of the user

{GET}: `https://graph.facebook.com/USERIDFROMPREVIOUSREQUEST?fields=id,name,email&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`

I think you want to save all these information to a database and create a session in order to keep the user logged in and therefore all the requests described will be useful for you in a real application.

After doing all the backend stuff, you're ready for the redirection using deep link. To do that, set a meta-tag to redirect the inappbrowser to your application:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL={YOURAPPSDEEPLINKNAME}://{SOMEPATHYOUWANTTOEND}" />`